# Pasar un tipo polimórfico como argumento en SoapUI al user ServiceKnownType en un servicio WCF

Tags: soap, soapui, wcf, servicio

Tengo un servicio WCF. Este servicio tiene una operacion que recibe un argumento de tipo `Request`. Esta es solo la clase padre, y cuando llamo la operación paso un valor de tipo `Request_v1`, que hereda de `Request`, y que tiene la implementación completa de lo que quiero enviar.

Cuando trato de probar el servicio usando SoapUI, puedo crear un envelope con el tipo `Request_V1` agregando el namespace correspondiente, pero por alguna razón, el servicio recibe el valor como si fuera de tipo `Request`

Leyendo acerca de ServiceKnowType encontré que tengo que especificar de alguna manera la relación de herencia en el cliente, pero no he encontrado como hacer esto en soapUI

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Postea el código de tus contratos (mejor un ejemplo mínimo con tu problema).

Comment: Postea tu archivo de configuración y métodos.

Comment: Muéstranos el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe pasar el tipo en el mensaje (con el XSI que corresponde)

```
<Request ins:type="d:Request_V1">
```